# How do I create a makefile for SDL2/C++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, include, sdl

As the title states I'm trying to create a makefile for compiling C++ programs using SDL2 on Windows. I have MinGW installed and working. I'm using Sublime 2 as my environment. Here's what I have so far:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++0x -g -O3 -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows
INCLFLAGS = -IC:\Libraries\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2
LDFLAGS = -LC:\Libraries\i686-w64-mingw32\lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
OBJECTS = main.o
TARGET = 1_hellosdl

$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(INCLFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

main.o :

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)

remake:
    clean $(TARGET)
```

Right now when I compile I get the following error:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -g -O3 -w -Wl,-subsystems,windows   -c -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
main.hpp:4:17: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
 #include <SDL.h>
```

So the issue is that `g++` can't find the SDL include file when it tries to compile main.cpp. I get that this is because `$(INCLFLAGS)` isn't being added to the line under `main.o :`.

Optimally, I'd like to specify `INCLFLAGS` implicitly similar to `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`, but based on [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) it doesn't look like it's possible.

Is there a way to do this using an implicit variable or, failing that, what's the best alternative? Is there anything else I am doing wrong?

Comment: I just fixed my own problem.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you could use CMake for library management and make file.

Comment: Know any good tutorials on CMake? I've heard about it but never used it...

Comment: No, but I've good some SDL2 CMakeLists.txt already done, just check my repository : https://github.com/jordsti/stigame  or  https://github.com/jordsti/LibreSTR

Comment: Cool, I'll check it out. I think it might be overkill for these smaller tutorial projects, but I'll definitely look at using it for bigger projects later on :)

Comment: Maybe overkill for a small projet like you said, but you will still learn how to use the tool ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by moving `$(INCLFLAGS)` into `$(CXXFLAGS)`:

```
INCLFLAGS = -IC:\Libraries\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2
CXXFLAGS = $(INCLFLAGS) -std=c++0x -g -O3 -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows
```

Additionally, I had to move `$(LDFLAGS)` to the end in order for it to link correctly:

```
$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)
```